# Getting the value from any dropdown wit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have for every day a dropdown where the user can change the working shift for the workers, always when the working shift is changed, I need to checkt the previeus and next working shift from the day where the dropdown was changed. I have found this jquery function which activates on any dropdown on the page when the user changes the vaule of the dropdown.

```
function testFu() {
$("select").on("change", function () {
    alert("Value: " + this.value);
});}
```

when I use it once everything is okay, but when I use it more than once in a row I get many popups like 9 or so and I dont get it why.

I havent used Jquery till now.

Comment: Where is `testFu()` called? There are several reasons your problem can occur. Calling that function more than once is the most likely one. Provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function once inside the alert tagName, and you need to make sure all the elements are nested inside the tagname  "select" so that you can apply the change on them all to

```js
$("select").on("change", function () {
    alert("Value: " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

gether.